# schema between local and remote servers

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I wrote using LINQ to communicate with the database - everything works fine, but I use MS-SQL Express server on my local machine for building it.

When it is ready, I publish it to the live box in a folder for testing. That works fine, too. But the server uses MS-SQL 2005 full - which isn't a problem except that when I make a DataContext using Linq to SQL, it prepends dbo. as the schema on my local machine - well, on the server box this isn't the case - so I always have to recreate my database tables.

Is there any work around to this? I cannot run anything but MS-SQL Express on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside visual studio in the dbml designer, click a table and look at the property Source

do you see the **dbo.**?

Comment: Yes - I can just delete that?